# Cin, остановка ввода на своем символе вместо пробела

Tags: c++, io, cin

Допустим есть код:

```
string s;
while (cin >> s)
    cout << s << endl;
```

При вводе Hello, world! программа выведет:

```
Hello,
world!
```

Можно ли сделать так чтобы cin останавливался например на 'o' и вывод был:

```
Hell
,w
rld!
```

*Спасибо*

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В программировании можно почти все, вопрос обычно только в количестве строк :)

Ваш вопрос решается в одну строку:

```
while(getline(cin,s,'o'))
```

Вот [тут](https://ideone.com/zv32pt) полный код.